# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent & Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.3

I have a record model and status model. Which each record has status can be "approved", "disapproved" or "in process" which is stored in the status model that connected trough status_id in the record model.
This is my model & their relationship.

```
Records(id, user_id, status_id, note, date, timestamp)

function status()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Status');
}

Statuses(id, name)

function record()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Record');

}
```

I would like to callback like this on my view $records->status->name. But it gives error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Statuses.record_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`record_id` = 3 and `statuses`.`record_id` is not null limit 1)
```

I try to to play the relationship & the callback but it not work. Is it possible to do that? Or better i just save the status directly on the record table without using the status record. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell us what your relevant table names are? Also did you setup foreign keys in your migrations?

Comment: Can you put your Migrations codes as well!

Answer (score 1):

You have the relationships reversed. Can you try the following instead:

```
class Record extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
    }
}

class Status extends Model
{
    public function records()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Record');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going for a 'One To Many', rather than a 'Many To Many' relationship.

Try the following instead:

```
Records(id, user_id, status_id, note, date, timestamp)

function status()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
}

Statuses(id, name)

function record()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Record');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Statuses.record_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`record_id` = 3 and `statuses`.`record_id` is not null limit 1)
```

According to the Error! It says that you don't have records_id in your status table. So add it.

For this to work on You should have a unsigned integer named as record_id in your Status Migration.

```
 $table->unsignedInteger('record_id')->references('id')->on('records');    //This will work as the foreign key to find the respective Status.
```

After editing the migration file you'll have to rollback migrations.
In terminal at your project directory,

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

If  you could add the migrations as well, It will be easier to point out.

Answer (score 0):

Define `hasOne` Relationship on `Records`

```
Records(id, user_id, status_id, note, date, timestamp)

function status(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Status','id','status_id');
}
```

and hasMany Relationship on Status

```
Statuses(id, name)

function record(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Record','status_id','id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model:Record    
Records(id,user_id,status_id,note)
function status(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Status','id);
}

model:Status
Status(id,name)
function record(){
return $this->hasmany('App\Record','id','status_id');
}

 Try this relation it will work
```

Comment: `ErrorException in 0abded5d613c35e174212ce480a87b7a6a95419a.php line 200:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/resources/views/records/timeline.blade.php)`

Thanks for your response. It shows error above. But it works when i google some more i need to do like this {{@$records->status->name}} or {{ $yourVar['value'] }}

Do you know why? Thanks.